# How to use Chrome in Google search bar on top?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, google-search

I don't like the Google search bar on top because of the blue bar on top and I can't change the search time range. How can I make the search bar just use normal Chrome Google search?

I use a OnePlus X with Android 5.1.1 Oxygen 2.2.1-X.

Answer (score 0):

Google Now: Settings -> Accounts & Privacy -> Open Web Pages in App

[image]